# How to echo current post title in comment form array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, comments, title

I have this code:

```
        comment_form( 
        array(
            'fields'                => $fields, 
            'comment_field'         => $comment_field, 
            'label_submit'          => 'Plaatsen', 
            'comment_notes_before'  => '', 
            'comment_notes_after'   => '', 
            'title_reply'           => 'Wat is jouw ervaring met'
        )
    );
```

I'd like to echo the current post title behind the title_reply array, like this:

```
'title_reply'           => 'Wat is jouw ervaring met <?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?> ? '
```

Can anyone help me do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'title_reply' => 'Wat is jouw ervaring met ' . get_the_title($ID)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding the point of this question. I thought he meant he wanted to concatenate the title to the end of the "title_reply" key.

Comment: @James Spence, actually i wanted to concatenate the title to the end of the "title_reply" key, so thanks for that!

The right code is:
comment_form( 
   array(
     'fields'     => $fields, 
    'comment_field'   => $comment_field, 
    'label_submit'    => 'Plaatsen', 
    'comment_notes_before'  => '', 
    'comment_notes_after'  => '', 
    'title_reply'    => 'Wat is jouw ervaring met' . get_the_title($ID)
   )
  );

Just one more question, how do i add a question mark behind the title?

Comment: The `.` operator concats strings together. So if you want to add additional strings, merely do `$stringOne . $stringTwo . "?"`. In this case, it'd be `'Wat is jouw ervaring met' . get_the_title($ID) . '?'`. That'll concat a "?" on the end of the string.

Comment: @JamesSpence i did exactly that but didnt add '' around the question mark. Thanks for the answer, i fell in love with stackoverflow:)

Comment: Happy to help. Would you mind checking the checkmark on the left side of this question, to signify that I answered your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below

```
$comment_form = array( 
    'fields' => $fields, 
    'comment_field' => $comment_field, 
    'label_submit' => 'Plaatsen', 
    'comment_notes_before' => '', 
    'comment_notes_after' => '', 
    'title_reply' => 'Wat is jouw ervaring met'
     );

`echo $comment_form['title_reply']; `
```